# My MacBook Pro makes three beeps during updating

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, install, software-update, shutdown

I would like to find out what caused my problem. A few days ago, I decided to upgrade my **MacBook Pro** to **High Sierra**, and somewhere in the beginning of the process, the computer ***suddenly shut down and then made three short beeps***. And the interesting thing is, when I turned the machine off forcely and turned it on again, the installation *continued like nothing happened*. Now *the same thing happened when I was installing the update that requiered the reboot*. I would just like to know what could happen, and how I could prevent it in the future.

Comment: Why did you turn the machine off forcefully?

Comment: Just got scared of the beeps. But when I turned it on, the installation continued, and no beeps happeened until the end of the process.

Answer (score 2):

- Three successive tones, then a five-second pause (repeating): RAM doesn't pass a data integrity check. If you recently replaced or upgraded your computer's RAM, check to see if it was installed properly.
- Three long tones, three short tones, three long tones: EFI ROM corruption is detected, and your Mac is in EFI ROM recovery mode. Newer computers automatically recover from a corrupted ROM; when this occurs, a progress bar appears on the screen during ROM recovery mode. Don't disturb your Mac while the ROM recovery takes place. When recovery is complete, your Mac restarts.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202768).

Comment: It's important to note that these beeps are *outside* the OS.  So if it happens again (pay close attention to the beep patterns reference here), you might want to run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting) and/or take it in for a profession al to look at it.

Comment: I've never run the diagnostics but will try to do it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I couldn't run Apple Diagnostics because I got the error -5010d.

Comment: According to [Krypted.com](https://krypted.com/lists/comprehensive-list-of-mac-os-x-error-codes/) : afpFileBusy = -5010, /* Cannot delete an open file */